# Air Pass to visit Pacific Islands

Tags: air-travel, tickets, budget, islands, pacific-ocean

I am interested in visiting some Pacific Islands, even though at the moment I have no specific plan about which to visit. I would like to have a look at how to get there and in particular island hopping flying passes that are available.

I found out about a few airlines that offer such passes but it is usually restricted to their own network (specific to a country), like Air Calédonie or Air Tahiti Nui.

However what sounds more appealing is the [Discover South Pacific Pass](https://www.allairpass.com/discover-south-pacific-pass/) that I found on the web - not on an airline nor a travel agent website. It mentions some codes and booking with a travel agent - that should not be located in Oceania, and I am currently in Oceania - but now, what should I do with that? I have been searching around the web to find whether an Online Travel Agent would sell it. Few websites mention this pass so I have no idea how reliable this is in the first place.

Is it likely that only "office-based travel agents" could sell that pass? Does anyone know if I could get that from some Online Travel Agent?

Comment: The [PDF](https://www.allairpass.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/discovery_south_pacific.pdf) also states that you have to combine it with "an international long-haul flight to the South Pacific, on one of the participating airlines."